# How to execute function after image is loaded into a div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, loading

I'm fairly new to jquery and still finding my way in it. I'm trying to execute a function, once an image is loaded into a specific div.

Here is the code I have.

```
$('#advanced-slideshow img').load(function() {
    var idx =  $('#mycarousel li a.activeSlide').data('index') - 2;
    carousel.scroll(idx);
    return false;
});
```

What I would like is each time and image is loaded into the div, #advanced-slideshow I want my function to execute.

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(function() {
 $('#advanced-slideshow img').each(function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
      //do stuff
    });
 });
});
```

Test the above code at **http://jsbin.com/aqiki4**